# How come mongodb timeseries have duplicate _id

Tags: mongodb, time-series, mongo-collection

I just realized mongodb timeseries two or more documents can have the same ID.

Is that normal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details like how you create/insert the documents?

Comment: I added two screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find it mentioned explicitly in the documentation, but there is no autogenerated unique index on _id field for time series collections.
From [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/timeseries-collections/),

> Time series collections behave like normal collections. You can insert
> and query your data as you normally would. MongoDB treats time series
> collections as writable non-materialized views backed by an internal
> collection. When you insert data, the internal collection
> automatically organizes time series data into an optimized storage
> format. When you create a time series collection, MongoDB
> automatically creates an internal clustered index on the time field.

Example:

```
db.createCollection(
    "weather",
    {
       timeseries: {
          timeField: "timestamp",
          metaField: "metadata",
          granularity: "hours"
       }
    }
)
    
db.weather.insertMany( [
   {
      "metadata": "temperature",
      "timestamp": ISODate("2022-05-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "temp": 12
   },
   {
      "metadata": "temperature",
      "timestamp": ISODate("2022-05-18T02:00:00.000Z"),
      "temp": 11
   },
   {
      "metadata": "temperature",
      "timestamp": ISODate("2022-05-18T04:00:00.000Z"),
      "temp": 9
   }
])
```

Now, if you query `system.buckets.weather` collection,

```
db.getCollection('system.buckets.weather').find({})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62843700f921421b34e56d1f"),
    "control" : {
        "version" : 1,
        "min" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63b7a7460a8571fbefcb480b"),
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2022-05-17T17:30:00.000-06:30"),
            "temp" : 9.0
        },
        "max" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63b7a7460a8571fbefcb480d"),
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2022-05-17T21:30:00.000-06:30"),
            "temp" : 12.0
        }
    },
    "meta" : "temperature",
    "data" : {
        "timestamp" : {
            "0" : ISODate("2022-05-17T17:30:00.000-06:30"),
            "1" : ISODate("2022-05-17T19:30:00.000-06:30"),
            "2" : ISODate("2022-05-17T21:30:00.000-06:30")
        },
        "_id" : {
            "0" : ObjectId("63b7a7460a8571fbefcb480b"),
            "1" : ObjectId("63b7a7460a8571fbefcb480c"),
            "2" : ObjectId("63b7a7460a8571fbefcb480d")
        },
        "temp" : {
            "0" : 12.0,
            "1" : 11.0,
            "2" : 9.0
        }
    }
}
```

This [comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-59087) says this,

> The primary key index of a Time Series collection is an automatically
> created clustered index on a server generated unique _id value for a
> group of documents with a unique metaField for a time span. This index
> and value can be seen in the corresponding system.buckets.foo
> collection. The _id of the document cannot currently be indexed and
> cannot be the primary key index for a Time Series collection like a
> regular collection.